# Problems with Android billing sample app

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing

I followed all of the steps for running the Android billing sample app in http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-download

I succeeded to buy an item, but there are several issues:

1. when I select an item to buy, I first get an "Item not found" error, and when I click "ok" I see the product in google play. does this happen to anyone else?
2. I purchased several new items, I see on my google checkout account that the order is "shipped" BUT in the billing test app, under "Items you own" I don't see anything...
3. in http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-download they suggest to

> refund purchases that are made with test accounts, otherwise the
>   purchases will show up as actual payouts to your merchant account

where can I perform the refund? in my google checkout account the "Refund some money" item is greyed out...

Does anyone know how to handle these issues?

Answer (score 1):

They are several reasons

1. check your products are published or not.
2. your APK in draf mode or not.
3. Products must be Activate.
4. First create TestMails in developer console under Licence key.and your device must have using this mail id as primary mail id of device.
   [image]